# Custom Google Map Type not showing map type control options on android HTC Thunderbolt

Tags: google-maps-api-3, jquery-mobile, htc-thunderbolt

I'm writing an application that uses custom map types and you can choose which map to show from a drop down control over the map. Everything is working fine on iPhones and my LG android. I'm having problems on my friend and his wife's HTC Thunderbolts. On the thunderbolt, instead of the drop down showing my mapTypeIds list, it is only showing two options, Satellite and Map. They have the exact same problem on both phones.

The app is a jQuery mobile application.
Here is how I'm accessing the API if that might have anything to do with it

`<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>`

I'm also using this [jQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/) to make it easier to insert the map into my application.

Comment: JQuery mobile has some problems with HTC phones. This if it works on droids and iPhones, then this may be your issue

Comment: My father has an Incredible and it seemed to work. I just checked the platforms page of the jquery mobile website and the Incredible is under the tested Grade A browser platforms but I don't see the Thunderbolt in there at all.

Comment: Not all HTCs are unable to work with J-Mobile, but I know that there are ones that cannot. Assuming that the code for the map is correct, my first suggestion would be to make a regular html page with the map in it and try it on an HTC. I would also look into the OS of that particular phone, and see where that ranks on the [JQuery Mobile comparability sheet](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/)

Comment: Good idea with the regular html page, I'll try that. The reason I assume the code is ok is because it's working well with other mobile devices, just not the Thunderbolt.